# Simple Function within a function in C

Tags: c

I am doing something simple but I can't seem to get it to work.

Basically, I have main() that basically shows how a character is displayed in two different ways. However, I tried to jazz it up a bit and kind of make it loop. I could do this easier I know, but just trying to get my feet in the ground.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* displays code number for a character*/
char Chat(void);

int main(void)
{
    char ch, gr;
    printf(" please enter a character.\n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    printf("The code for %c is%d. \n", ch, ch);

    Chat(void);
        if (gr == 'y')

    main();
        else
    return 0;

}
/* this function should obtain the value of gr and then send it to main() so that main can avaluate if
it should run again*/

    char Chat(void)
{
   char gr;
   printf(" press y for again, press n for instant death");
   gr = getchar();
    return gr;

}
```

I hope what I am trying to do makes sense.... and I don't see the need to knock this down because I probably left some typo in... seriously people.

Comment: Make your `Chat(void);` line `gr = Chat();` ?

Comment: Change `Printf` to `printf`.

Comment: AHH, I did fix that at one point.. then I must have accidentally undid it.

Comment: @Rup I did what you said and it compiled... but it didn't run again.. nor did it ask me for input the second time.

Comment: From a quick experiment I think you've still got the return from your typing 'y', 'return' in the input buffer so it's returning `gr = 10` from that. You'll need to clear or ignore that somehow. Aside from making it a special case, e.g. `do { gr = getchar(); } while (gr == 10);`, I'm not sure what to suggest (and I don't really like that). I've never done console input in C.

Comment: Learn C from a textbook, print or electronic.  You don't have enough experience to turn to SO with questions like this yet.

Comment: @Chris I have added a corrected version of your program look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some pointers:

> 1. Start the function names with small letters. But that's just a convention in the most of the community.
> 2. Make sure you always return something in main.
> 3. Instead of calling `main();` (which is dangerous) inside main, you can use a `do-while` loop, which is better.
>
>    **4. Passing void at Chat(void) is not valid.**
> 4. You are not using the return value of Chat(void) any where.
> 5. `else` before `return 0` is not needed.
> 6. **`getchar()` swallows the inputs such as `\n` characters that were intended to enter previous inputs.**

That `swallow` caused the program to stop in one rotation. I have changed your code and added below. And `do-while` version is given separately under that.

Few getchars added to the code inorder to remove some logical errors and Chat(void) is removed for correcting compiler error:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
    /* displays code number for a character*/
    char Chat(void);

    int main(void)
    {
        char ch, gr;
        printf(" please enter a character.\n");
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        getchar();  //swallows newline
        printf("The code for %c is %d. \n", ch, ch);
        gr=Chat();
        if (gr == 'y')
           main();  // this is not a good idea....
        return 0;
    }
    char Chat(void)
    {
       char gr;
       printf(" press y for again, press n for instant death");
       gr = getchar();
       getchar();  // swallows newline
        return gr;

    }
```

**EDIT:** This is the `do-while` version of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
    /* displays code number for a character*/
    char Chat(void);

    int main(void)
    {
        char ch, gr;
        do{
            printf(" please enter a character.\n");
            scanf("%c", &ch);
            getchar();  //swallows newline
            printf("The code for %c is %d. \n", ch, ch);
            gr=Chat();
       }while(gr=='y');
        return 0;
    }
   char Chat(void)
    {
       char gr;
       printf(" press y for again, press n for instant death");
       gr = getchar();
       getchar();  // swallows newline
        return gr;

    }
```

Comment: Points 1 - 6 , all good! `votes++;`

Comment: Why is "start function names with small letters" a good point? It's purely stylistic, and, some would argue, meaningless (or even flat-out wrong - there's style for you). Additionally, calling `main` directly is **BAD** according to the standard. Per §3.6.1.3 we are told that: "*the function `main` shall not be used within a program*".

Comment: @NikBougalis edited my first point .... the asker mention he could do it with loop but wanted to experiment....that's why I left the code with `main` call and added the point in list.... thanks anyway :)

Comment: Additionally, `getchar` returns an `int`. Stuffing it into a `char` can cause weird issues if the `EOF` is not representable as a `char`.

Comment: @NikBougalis so what's the alternative ?

Comment: Thanks man. I am just experimenting, but thanks for letting me know about some of those practices.  I am just getting started, although I have a half decent foundation in some areas to pick up structure.. just need some pointers. Thanks.

Comment: Now that I look at it, it makes sense. I probably was trying to use some knowledge I had from some other languages and tried to mix things up in ways that it doesn't. Thanks!!

Comment: @Chris going from lower level (C) languages to higher level language (Java) doesn't make such a confusion as if it's in reverse...) you are welcome :)

Comment: So I have learned. When I was little, I had so many interests. I got a book on C and it basically killed my brain, mostly because I didn' tknow what to do. Now I can get it, and so when I have free time at work> it is what I am doing. Maybe I can use it sometime.

Comment: @Chris yeah... `C` is still used.. but mostly in `Operating Systems` code and for `Drivers`...